# How can I position these divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I cannot get some `div`s in a list to be side by side, they go to the next line.

Can someone please show me how it is done.

I am referring to the section at the bottom right side of the web-page that has images of the movie stacked up in the underlying link.

[sugestmovie.net](http://suggestmovie.net/)

Comment: Add **float: left** to your 'li' item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways.

**Method 1**: In your code, instead of set the `display` from <strike>`inline`</strike> to `inline-block`. This must solve your issue. And the edit must resemble as follows:

```css
.bookmarkedMovies li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Method 2**: Or just, `float` the required `div` tag to `left`.

```css
.bookmarkContainer {
    float: left;
    /*required css*/
}
```

Anyone of the above will work just fine...

Comment: This worked the best because it kept the height of .graybox the same. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add at the class "bookmarkContainer" the attribute float with the value "left"

```
.bookmarkContainer {
    /* other css rules ... */
    float: left;
}
```

Edit: I tried with Firebug and it works fine, in the picture above you can see it working, also i added `margin: 10px;` and before the `ul` closing element i add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` which allow the parent container wrap the list items.
I
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you need `float: left;`. Along with a margin you should have exactly what you want. You'll obviously need to adjust the margin based on your needs.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q291a74z/)

```
.bookmarkContainer {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

Also, when dealing with floats always clear them afterwards or it will mess up the content following it.

```
<div style="clear:both;">
```